# I am not able to configure Document Library webpart in Sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, web-part

Since yesterday I am not able to configure Document Library webpart. When I try adding folder structure, and click on "Apply", it just doesnt work. All configurations vanish automatically.

Pls help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about how the web part not work? In SharePoint online or on premise?

Comment: Online. I created a newpage on my Sharepoint Online site. Then, clicked on + button to add a web part. After that I selected Document Library web part. Clicked on edit webpart and tried to enter folder name. When i click on "Apply" , the folder name vanishes

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, this issue happens occasionally.

I add the document library web part in the home page, then fill in the folder name> click Apply, the folder name missing, however the document view will show the files in this folder.

Today, I test again, the issue disappers and the web part works well.

[image]

Please try to add the web part in different page then check the result.